# redirect all http requests

Tags: php, redirect

My company uses Xerox Docushare for document management. We are consolidating 2 docushare servers into one. Assuming users have a lot of docushare pages bookmarked in their browser, is it possible to place a php file in the root folder which will receive all these requests and perform a redirect.

For example

`http://old-server/docushare/dsweb/View/Collection-xxxx`

would get redirected to

`http://new-server/docushare/dsweb/View/Collection-yyyy`

The collection-xxxx to collection-yyyy would probably come from a file we intend to generate as part of the conversion.

I did take a look at 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php
but that is on a url level whereas i am looking to convert all requests on the older path.

Thanks.

Comment: What's the difference between the "URL level" and what you're trying to do?

Comment: @deceze i meant to say if i have index.php at the root level docushare, it will only receive requests at "//server/docushare" and not for example under "//server/docushare/dsweb".

Comment: What you want to look into is URL rewriting and/or mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By my opinion, the simplest way is to put **.htaccess file**. In the root of your document root

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old-server
RewriteRule http://old-server/docushare/dsweb/View/(.*)$ http://new-server/docushare/dsweb/View/$1 [R=301,L]
```

For more inspiration check [this page](http://www.webweaver.nu/html-tips/web-redirection.shtml)

---

The **PHP way**

In front controller or whatever is hitten as first by web server, will be condition, using [$_SERVER](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) variable, similar to this

```
if($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'old-server')
{
  $redirectionPath = str_replace('http://old-server/docushare/dsweb/View/', 'http://new-server/docushare/dsweb/View/', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
  header(sprintf('Location: %s', $redirectionPath), 301);
}
```

This is the ugly way and you should not use it unless you have no other choice. Not to mention my blind written code ;)

I don't know exactly in what situation you are, but i think the .htaccess file solution solves issue you are experiencing

Comment: The reason we cannot use .htaccess file is because there are approximately 15000 "Collection-xxx" urls being renamed to "Collection-yyyy". During the mergre process, the new name is spit out. For ex: Collection-0001 in old system is now renamed to Collection-1001 in the new system. The reason we want to put some script is because we would want to display an intermediate page to inform the user that his old bookmark should be renamed etc.

Comment: From my experience users will not change the bookmark. Show them 404 page, if you want them to change the bookmark, or redirect them to the new document's url if you want to keep it working. If the "filenames" will be changed i think you need bit a more sofisticated mapping logic, than rewrites or one condition in index.php